# How to get an ndgrid from a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

`V` is a 3D matrix with uniformly spaced voxels. A way to get a coordinate grid / meshgrid would be:

```
[x y z] = ndgrid( 1:size(V,1), 1:size(V,2), 1:size(V,3) );
```

which feels redundant, especially if the number of dimensions is even higher. Is there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do it like this is you have a lot of dimensions (or a changing number of dimensions):

```
C = arrayfun(@(x)(1:size(V,x)),1:ndims(V),'UniformOutput',false);
[outArgs{1:ndims(V)}] = ndgrid(C{:})
```

So now using your example

```
outArgs{1} == x;
outArgs{2} == y;
outArgs{3} == z;
```

But for 3 dimensions, either leave it has you have it or else maybe you'll find this neater:

```
[m, n, p] = size(V);
[x, y, z] = ndgrid(1:m, 1:n, 1:p);
```